# Unknown module QT: webkit

Tags: c++, qt, webview, webkit, qt5

I am trying to make a simple webview in Qt 5.6

in my .pro file I have

```
QT       += webkitwidgets
```

I have this Error:

```
:-1: error: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Qt 5.6 Qt WebKit was removed:

https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.6

> With Qt 5.6 the following modules are no longer part of the release packages, but users can still build them from source:   Qt WebKit

So if you still want to use WebKit you need 5.5 or earlier or you need to build your own version from sources.